# 504 Gateway timeout from SharePoint 2013 CSOM with SAML Authentication

Tags: c#, sharepoint, saml-2.0, csom

We have ADFS and SAML authentication with onprem SharePoint 2013. I am using the msdn sample from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/remote-authentication-in-b7b6f43c) .

I get the `ClientContext` object but on `ExecuteQuery()` I am getting 504 Gateway Timeout.

I am just trying to retrieve title, why is it timing out? What else could go wrong?

```
            using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
            {
                if (ctx != null)
                {
                    ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w=>w.Title,w=>w.Description); // Query for Web
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute
                    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();`? Is there a reason for not doing a `ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync(onPass, onFail);`?

Comment: I am not using silverlight. BTW this is c#